# Ruby on Rails - could not load postgres adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Building a rails app on heroku (locally).  Following their tutorials for [rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4), and [installing postgres locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup).

When ever I run the server or generate a migration I get the following err:

> LoadError (Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/posgtres_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.):

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
  username: Name
  password: secret
  host: localhost
```

Gem file has: gem 'rails' '4.2.0', and gem 'pg' installed

my machine's OS: Windows 64x

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful this is the same issue you are having but, posting these details in case it gives a lead.  I'm using Windows 10

I had the same error message. To troubleshoot, I tried to do a reinstall of pg with 'gem install pg' but a file was locked.

Found I had a process still using one of the PG files and shut down the process, deleted the entire pg directory found at C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\pg-0.18.3-x64-mingw32

Reran 'gem install pg' rake db:setup, rake db:create, rake db:migrate and the error was gone.